# Is there a way to avoid re-downloading maven dependencies again and again when we use the Karate project with docker images?

Tags: maven, karate, mvn-repo

its obvious that normally for our project, when we run the mvn test, then firstly it download the dependencies and store it to our local /home/username/.m2 and then it will be going to use for the next time when we run our mvn test.
But we we use the mvn image in Dockerfile, is there a way to do the same (except using the volume or mount concept)???...

Comment: Why not using the volume/mount concept?

Comment: Welcome to SO! It will be easier for people knowing Karate to find this question if you put Karate in the title (e.g. When building a Karate-project via docker, can avoid to download the dependencies every time). The tag of course also helps, but titles are always read. The kotlin tag doesn't really matter to this question, so you might as well drop it.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the developer guide: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/Developer-Guide#docker

> Note that the -v "$HOME/.m2":/root/.m2 re-uses your local Maven JAR download "cache" (which saves time)

Also note that you can build your own image based on the Maven docker image, refer to the docs and look for the section `Packaging a local repository with the image`: https://hub.docker.com/_/maven

Comment: Poster explicit wrote not to use the mount/volume approach.

Comment: @khmarbaise which doesn't make sense :) so I hope this answer helps others. and I have 2 options proposed, the second one can bundle the dependencies in the image

Answer (score 1):

You may create an intermediate container, building on top of Maven container you already use.

- Execute `mvn dependency:go-offline` as the last build step of the intermediate container;
- Tag the intermediate container in Docker;
- Use tagged intermediate container as the base container for the build.

Maven will download new/missing dependencies, but intermediate container will store the major part of required local repository already.

You would need to re-create intermediate container (and tag it) after major changes to the dependencies in the project.